# R: Successfully created table extracting function from docx, but failed to connect to a folder

Tags: r, extract, docx

I created a function extracting tables from docx files and combined them as one data set successfully with a sample folder of 4 docx files.

Then I linked the function to a folder with 500 files, and all of sudden, error came.

```
> lapply(files, FUN=docTodata) 
  Error: Cannot find 'marginversion1.docx'
```

This is the code, and I omit here the middle of the path that has my name.

```
# read all files in a directory
files<-list.files(path="C:/Users/...../files")
print(files)
```

When printing files, **it successfully prints all the file names in the folder**!!!!! but lapply() does not read files.

Comment: No, it still says the same error.

Comment: If you can show a small reproducible example, it can be tested

Comment: I added two example I created.. (but don; know how to link docx files to here)

Comment: Have you tried a `for` loop i.e. `out <- vector('list', length(files)); for(i in seq_along(files)) out[[i]] <- docTodata(files[i])`

Comment: I guess the error showed would be an issue with some of the elements.  You could wrap with `tryCatch` and check where it is going wrong

Comment: I tried to use loop but the it kept causing errors and simplified it.. sorry what is tryCatch? where should I have to put it?

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) should help for writing trycatch

Comment: Is your working directory identical with the one that contains the files? Otherwise maybe you need to use `files<-list.files(path="C:/Users/...../files", full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: Does the function work correctly with 1 file? What does `docTodata(files[1])` return?

Comment: @user12728748 omg this works!!!